# Navigationbar right button is not placed correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem

I implemented a `UITabBarController` with 4 items.

I set the initial `ViewController` from `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    HomeTabBarViewController* homeVC = [[HomeTabBarViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window setRootViewController:homeVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Here is  `HomeTabBarViewController` `ViewDidLoad` Code:

```
UIViewController *view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [view1.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIViewController *view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * centerNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
    HomePagingViewController * view3=(HomePagingViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePagingViewController"];
     UINavigationController * centerNav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view3];
    UIViewController *view4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * centerNav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view4];
    [view2.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [view3.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [view4.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:centerNav];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:centerNav3];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:centerNav4];

    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
    view1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home"
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab_item.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_tab_item_active.png"]] ;
    view2.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bookmark"
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_tab_item.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_tab_item_active.png"]];
    view3.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Paper"
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper_tab_item.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper_tab_item_active.png"]];
    view4.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More"
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_tab_item.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_tab_item_active.png"]];
```

In `HomePagingViewController` `ViewDidLoad` I setUp a Navigation as in code

```
-(void)navigationSetUp{
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=NO;

    UIBarButtonItem * settingBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuHandler:)];
    UIBarButtonItem * searchBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuHandler:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingBtn;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBtn;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ie_New_logo.png"]];
}
```

After this when I changed the tab for `HomePagingViewController` the navigation right button not placed correctly there is no margin from right.

Refer Image : 
[image]

Please Help.

Comment: i have used same code i was not able to get padding issue try to set background color for right button and find the issue.

Comment: Hi @vinodh , I resolved the issue . You are right there is no issue with the code . Actually for Epaper we using third party SDK So that this problem occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue , there is no issue with the code . Actually for Epaper we using third party SDK So that this problem occur.I Removed SDK & the code is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you should think `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` effect.

- eg:
  `UIBarButtonItem * space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];`

--

- Why use a system navigation bar ？Custom navigation bar is nice！like:https://github.com/chenliangloveyou/EasyNavigation